# Combination of mmap() and memalign() in Linux/GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, memory-management, linux-kernel

I need to allocate some memory chunk in my C++ program with two requirements. First the address of the allocation needs to be aligned on the chunk size, second it needs to be allocated below 4GB virtual address space.

`memalign()` helps me with the first requirement, and `mmap()` helps me with the second, since I can pass `MAP_32BIT` flag as a parameter. But is it possible to somehow combine them both in a simple solution? (Technically of course I can use `mmap()` with any address I want, but the solution probably won't be very portable).

Comment: Why isn't that memory allocated by the device driver?

Comment: Why do you use `mmap`? how about `malloc`? could you tell me the reason?

Comment: Because I can't tell malloc to allocate below 4GB, and my program is compiled in 64-bit. In Visual Studio I could use /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO, but as far as I know there's nothing similar in GCC.

Comment: @user1483597 `mmap()` always gives you page-aligned memory by construction.

Comment: On x86, `gcc -m32 ...` will compile a 32-bit binary.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: @FUZxxl I need it to be aligned to something bigger than page

Comment: @user1483597 I'm curious as to why you need that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I need the code itself to be compiled in 64 bit, but that specific buffer address to be 32-bit wide. Sounds weird, but that's what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mmap a block that is (first rounded to the next power of) twice as big as what you need and then munmap what is not needed.

Comment: Good idea, but I thought that there might be something more simple.

Comment: @user1483597, might be, but I've seen my answer multiple times in production code, so I guess it is the simplest solution. Btw.: An answer marked as solved often does not attract visitors anymore. Best wait a day or two before marking my answer as accepted, so you can maybe get a better solution.